# Android OnClickListener error

Tags: android

I'm following a Lynda tutorial and trying to implement OnClickListener in my MainActivity class. The problem is I'm getting an error, shown below:

[image]

I was wondering if anyone had any insight why there is this error? It seems to work for the Lynda expert, but maybe it's because the tutorial is a little dated?

Thanks,
Allen

Comment: just click on the **"Add Unimplemented methods"** and then do what action you want for button in **"onClick( )"** method

Comment: thanks guys. i got it now :)

Comment: I would suggest you, also PL check [this](http://rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/04/start-activity-from-activity.html) tutorial for information and help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to **add unimplemented methods of Interface onClickListener** in your activity.. Just select first option. **Add Unimplemented methods**

Eclipse will automatically add `onClick()` to your Activity..

Answer (score 1):

That is not error you should click on Add unimplemented methods hyperlink to remove that error.

You have implemented `onClickListener` Interface but yet to implement the `onClick()` so it shows the Error. By Clicking the Add unimplemented methods, you can remove that error.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing onClicklistener.it is an interface so you have to implement all of its method.
As you will implement its methods you won't get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on Add unimplemented methods. And override onClick Method to do your work.

Hope [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html) helps you understand basics of implementing `Interfaces` in java

And whenever Eclips give you some suggestion try it first. It will auto suggest many things, e.g. Cast to ImageView, Cast to EditText, Import some package. That might be necessary for what you might be trying to.

Answer (score 1):

Select first option becoz you have implemented `onclicklistner` interface. this interface will implements a `onclick()` method.  And in this method you can code.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error add unimplemented methods..

It will be like this..

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class sampl extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.intentpage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ///  

        ///use any task  to perform
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java, whenever we implement an interface to our class, we always need to define all the methods in our class whose prootype is already in the interface. That is why it is asking you to implement those unimplemented methods in your class.